# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in Linux server

Tags: linux, file-get-contents, internal-server-error

I want to get feeds from here http://laimoon.com/feed/jobs?search=female,arts&locations=2
If i directly browse this page in browser it show feed, also If i use this code in my local host which is on windows

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://laimoon.com/feed/jobs?search=female,arts&locations=2"); 
print_r($file_contents); 
                  OR
$file_contents = file_get_contents('http://laimoon.com/feed/jobs?search=female,arts&locations=2')
print_r($xml);

Both works fine
```

But if i use this code in my linux live server then it shows this error for
 **file_get_contents()**

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(http://laimoon.com/feed/jobs?search=female,arts&locations=2): failed to open stream :HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

And this error for **simplexml_load_file()**

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://laimoon.com/feed/jobs?search=female,arts&locations=2): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 500 Server error is a problem at the server end. You probably can't do much about that. However, the `file_get_contents()` URL wrapper isn't as robust as it might be. Using [curl()](http://nz1.php.net/curl) might work for you.

Comment: But if this error is from server end then why it doesn't occurs when i directly request to that URL from my browser?

Comment: As I said - the wrapper isn't that good. Sometimes a server will return a 500 error just because it doesn't like the request. I have had similar trouble with it. I've found curl() is generally more reliable. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: Ok i am trying to use it via Curl

Comment: It again gives 500 error even i use CURL

Comment: I can't add anything. You'd need to talk to the site owners.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting 500 error when using file\_get\_contents(), but works in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524748/why-im-getting-500-error-when-using-file-get-contents-but-works-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my expected results, I'd just enable `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` in curl link and i got my result but there is one more problem that is now solved...
After this i load that xml data using `simplexml_load_string($ret);`

but it were not reads the CDATA then i add just two more parameters

```
 simplexml_load_string($ret,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Then i got my expected result...
Here is my complete code

```
$header = array('Content-Type:application/xml', 'Accept' => 'application/atom+xml, application/rss+xml, application/rdf+xml;q=0.9, application/xml;q=0.8, text/xml;q=0.8, text/html;q=0.7, unknown/unknown;q=0.1, application/unknown;q=0.1, */*;q=0.1');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://laimoon.com/feed/jobs?search=female,arts&locations=2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $loginFields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($ret,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$chl = $xml->children()->children();
$items = $chl->item;
foreach($items as $item){
  echo (string)$item->title."</br>";
  echo (string)$item->description."</br>";
  echo (string)$item->pubDate."</br>";
  echo (string)$item->link."</br>";

}
```

Thanks @Mike W

Answer (score 0):

User-agent is not set, set user_agent in php.ini or from command like:

`ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36');`