# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents, urlencode

I'm retrieving and saving images from a external source to my webserver by URL's. Unfortaley sometimes I get the following error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.

When I visit the given url with my browser the image is shown and valid. The url:

```
http://****.com/00/s/NTgwWDcyNg==/z/7LEAAMXQVT9TCcxx/$_85.JPG
```

The code which I use:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1\r\n", 'timeout' => "360"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);                                         
$imageString = file_get_contents(urldecode(urlencode($filename)), false, $context);                                            
$save = file_put_contents(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/tmp/' . $id . '_' . $sequenceNumber . '.jpg', $imageString);
```

Anyone has a idea why I get a 500 error?

Comment: whats with urlencode and urldecode ?

Comment: i've had tested a other image url with phpfiddle which gave also a 500 error, with urlencode/urldecode i've fixed this. When processing this url in phpfiddle I got a can't resolve host, fixed with a @ before file_get_contents. But what does the @?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting 500 error when using file\_get\_contents(), but works in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524748/why-im-getting-500-error-when-using-file-get-contents-but-works-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 5):

The following answer worked for me: [PHP file_get_contents 500 Internal Server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524748/php-file-get-contents-500-internal-server-error)

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$header = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com', FALSE, $context);
```