# file_get_contents returning error 500 when page exists

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I am trying to scrape some data from [this webpage](http://www.jackwills.com/en-GB/ladies/sale).

I have begun by using this code:

```
$list_url = "http://www.jackwills.com/en-GB/ladies/sale";
$html = file_get_contents($list_url);
echo $html;
```

However, it's returning the website's error 500 despite the fact that `file_get_contents()` works with other domains.

Is there a workaround that lets me grab the page I'm after?

**UPDATE**

Setting `ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');` has got me halfway there and I now see an HTML page with no styling. The information I need is generated by JavaScript - is there any way to get that?

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/q6k2rQ

Comment: Works fine.. cannot reproduce...

Comment: Is your configuration set to allow you to open URLs? http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: It works fine with other URLs, just not this one.

Comment: @AmalMurali looking at that link it doesn't work there - that's the error page (though my mistake, it's 500 not 404). [This](http://www.jackwills.com/en-GB/ladies/sale) is the page I'm expecting to see. Unless even within that page it's working differently for me!

Comment: Same problem/solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524748/php-file-get-contents-500-internal-server-error

Comment: @Sebastian So did the workaround in the solution of the question I linked to not work for you?

Comment: It gets me halfway there! The HTML for the right page loads, but no JavaScript which seems to be generating most of the content that I need.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. check your php.ini related setting such as "allow_url_fopen" that must be on:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you have there is the contents of my `php.ini` file.