# file_get_contents stopped working (Dropbox file)

Tags: php, dropbox, file-get-contents

I store some files in the public folder and call these using the php function `file_get_contents()`.

This was working fine up until a few weeks ago, then suddenly, it no longer works.

Has something changed on Dropbox? I checked to see if the issue is with the file, so I placed it on another server and it works fine.

However, when trying to call the file from Dropbox, it doesn't work at all.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Dropbox is 'just' an addon on a physical available folder. The reason why you can't use the function anymore can lay in permissions. Do you get any error back? What are the folder/file permissions?

Comment: `"no longer works"` is not very descriptive. Please detail exactly what is going wrong - are you getting an error? The wrong file? In addition, please include the **relevant** code you are using to retrieve the files.

Comment: I've had issues with file locking when trying to read/write to files in actively-synchronized Dropbox folders. I realize it probably defeats the entire purpose of what you're trying to do with Dropbox, but try pausing synchronization and seeing if it works.

Comment: Cross-linking https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=118410 from the Dropbox API forum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting 500 error when using file\_get\_contents(), but works in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524748/why-im-getting-500-error-when-using-file-get-contents-but-works-in-a-browser)