# simplexml_load_file warning error

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple function that converts address string into longitude and latitude using simple XML from Google. I get this weird warning error once in a while:

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=&sensor=true):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal
>   Server Error in /search_results.php on line 193
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity
>   "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=&sensor=true"
>   in /search_results.php on line 193 url not loading

Is there a better way to do this to avoid this error?

My code is below:

```
$geo_address = urlencode($address);

$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$geo_address."&sensor=true";

  $xml =  simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die ("url not loading");
  $status = $xml->status;
  if ($status=="OK") {
    $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
    $lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
  }
```

Comment: It seems your internal php file `(search_results.php)` has the problem `HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error` , and you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524748/php-file-get-contents-500-internal-server-error) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you're trying to geocode an empty address. You should verify the $geo_address length before querying google

```
$geo_address = urlencode($address);

if(strlen($geo_address)>0) {

    $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$geo_address."&sensor=true";

    $xml =  simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die ("url not loading");
    $status = $xml->status;
    if ($status=="OK") {
      $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
    }
} else {
  die('Invalid address');
}
```

you should replace the die() with some other error management logic that suits your app.