# file_get_contents throws 400 Bad Request error PHP

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I'm just using a `file_get_contents()` to get the latest tweets from a user like this:

```
$tweet = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/User.json'));
```

This works fine on my localhost but when I upload it to my server it throws this error:

> **Warning:** file_get_contents(http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/User.json) [function.file-get-contents]:failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request...

Not sure what might be causing it, maybe a php configuration I need to set on my server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/file-get-contents-returning-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed

Comment: Please see [this stack question][1] as it will probably answer you question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710147/php-get-content-of-http-400-response

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You might want to try using curl to retrieve the data instead of file_get_contents. curl has better support for error handling:

```
// make request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/User.json"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

// convert response
$output = json_decode($output);

// handle error; error output
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {

  var_dump($output);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

This may give you a better idea why you're receiving the error. A common error is hitting the rate limit on your server.

Comment: You should print `curl_error($ch)` to get a more detailed error.

Comment: question is about `file_get_contents`. suddenly an accepted `curl` answer shows up. what happened? am i missed something?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `file_get_contents` adding the `ignore_errors` option set to `true`, in this way you will get the entire body of the response in case of error (HTTP/1.1 400, for example) and not only a simple `false`.

You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479968/3926617

If you want access to response's headers, you can use `$http_response_header` after the request.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Answer (score 2):

Just a little addendum on Ben's answer.
According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) the CURLOPT_URL option may be set when inizializing the cURL handle with curl_init().

```
// make request
$ch = curl_init("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/User.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

// convert response
$output = json_decode($output);

// handle error; error output
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {

  var_dump($output);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before file_get_contents

```
 stream_context_set_default( [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
        'http' => [
            'ignore_errors' => true,
        ]
    ]);
```