# Ignoring errors in file_get_contents HTTP wrapper?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

The following code is to query an online thesaurus for a search engine I'm building as a college project, but I'm having problems with `file_get_contents` *"failed to open stream"* errors. When I send a word the thesaurus doesn't recognize, it throws up an error. I'm trying to write a piece of code that will *ignore the error* and just proceed without the information.

```
$thesaurus_search="http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/0089388bb57f/".$this->formatted_query."/php";
$result_thesaurus=file_get_contents($thesaurus_search);
```

I tried:

```
if (file_get_contents($thesaurus_search) != NULL)
{ // do stuff }
```

...but its not working because it still returns some sort of string.

What can I do to handle such cases?

Comment: What exactly does it return when there is an error? Some html? xml? json? You'd have to parse the returned data to check for the error codes - it's unlikely an api would simply return nothing.

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a piece of code that will ignore the error and just proceed without the information"*. How would you proceed without the information?

Comment: Maybe I should be a little more specific, this code is part of a class, the information it returns is not intrinsic to the end product, its just a bonus. So if file_get_contents is returning an error(because it doesnt have a match for the word) I want to break out of the class altogether, and not return any code.

Comment: Because you should not check for NULL, but for FALSE like this if($result_thesaurus !== false) (  do_whatever with $result_thesaurus } else { do_whatever you like, but don't use $result_thesaurus because it contains the error message  }

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you don't want `file_get_contents` to report *HTTP errors* as PHP Warnings, then this is the **clean** way to do it, using a stream context (there is something *specifically for that*):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),
));

$result = file_get_contents('http://your/url', false, $context);
```

Comment: Thanks Netcoder thats much better, appreciate your help. I'll stop hitting my computer with wrenches too :)

Comment: Thanks much! I found it within the manual after much probing, but it wasn't readily apparent to me a context option could help. It'd be nice if this were right on the file_get_contents page.

Comment: this is one of those things that's been annoying me for a while but didn't bother til now.  `@` should work but doesn't which is stupid. "**PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.**" seems simple enough but is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution if you're okay with just bailing out, would be:

```
if (empty($thesaurus_search)) { 
   return;
} else {
   //process with value
}
```

To more fully handle it, looking at the [API](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php), it looks like you should be checking the [response header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php), e.g.:

```
$thesaurus_search="http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/0089388bb57f/".$this->formatted_query."/php";
$result_thesaurus=file_get_contents($thesaurus_search);
if ($http_response_header[0] = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    //code to handle words
} else {
    // do something else?
}
```

Comment: Considering `file_get_contents` already returns `false` on error, I don't think that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly you are trying to make an API call to `http://words.bighugelabs.com`.
You need cURL to achieve this so if you have cURL installed then this code will work for you.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$thesaurus_search="http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/0089388bb57f/".$this->formatted_query."/php";
$options = array();
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $thesaurus_search;
$options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// Print result.
print_r(curl_close($ch));
```

Comment: *"You need cURL to achieve this"*, no he doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You might try curl:

```
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```