# file_get_contents change "&" to "&amp"

Tags: php, file-get-contents, ampersand

I want get json from a url with `file_get_contents` but it replace `&` with `&amp` and it dosnt work this way
 i tried curl and happened again
i try url directly too and it worked ,so url haven't problem

```html
$url="https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/asdkljsadlkjsd/sms/send.json?receptor=09148523669&sender=100005252&message=testing";


$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo "1";
var_dump($json);
```

and this is the result:

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/asdkljsadlkjsd/sms/send.json?receptor=09148523669&sender=100005252&message=testing):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in C:\wamp64\www\te\func\testjson.php on line 22

Of course stackoverflow remove `&amp` from  result url.

Comment: your code doesn't have &amp right?

Comment: URLs are encoded so it converts URL specific char to ist equivalent. You just need to decode url before using it.

Comment: yes my code dos not have &amp but file_get_contents add url "&amp"

Comment: i try decode url  it seems that not effect

Answer (score 0):

The trouble seems to be that it's returning an error status code. If so then see:
[Ignoring errors in file_get_contents HTTP wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475657/ignoring-errors-in-file-get-contents-http-wrapper/11479968#11479968)

```
$url="https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/asdkljsadlkjsd/sms/send.json?receptor=09148523669&amp;sender=100005252&amp;message=testing";

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),));
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $json;
```

Comment: this is the result :'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>

<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>

<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>

</BODY></HTML>

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Comment: I've removed the json header from the code... naturally if it's not json it won't parse as json. Sorry, I'm really not clear what you're trying to do any more.

Answer (score -2):

this is the answer :

```html
$url = 'https://example.url?';

// http_build_query builds the query from an array
$query_array = array (
    'search' => $string,
    'from' => $from,
    'to' => $to,
    'format' => 'json'
);

$query = http_build_query($query_array);
$result = file_get_contents($url . '&' . $query);
```