# PHP: How to GET request a page and get body and http error codes

Tags: php

I want know if is possible to get the HTTP error codes and response in case of error instead of false (file get contents error) and error throwed. I'm using file_get_contents on PHP 7.2

I already tried doing this:
`$r = file_get_contents("https://somewebsite");`

Output:
`PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://somewebsite): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`
I can get the response code with $http_response_header but $r is false and i want get the error response page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "error response page"?

Comment: I mean the page body .

Comment: Is a JSON response. I'm sure that is generated by the server and not the browser.

Comment: You can either use cURL or, even better, some of the tried and tested http-libraries out there if you want better control over the reqeust and response.

Comment: @MicioInformatico  How do you know there is a JSON response if you're saying that `$r` is `false`?

Comment: The response is generated by a php script : `http_response_code(400);
echo json_encode([...]);` and i tested it in my browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring errors in file\_get\_contents HTTP wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475657/ignoring-errors-in-file-get-contents-http-wrapper)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't test the accepted answer but now i tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with curl

```
$ch = curl_init('https://httpstat.us/404');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// if you want to follow redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// you may want to disable certificate verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpCode >= 400) {
    // error
    // but $response still contain the response
} else {
    // everything is fine
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using file get contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479968/11433886)

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),
));

$result = file_get_contents('http://your/url', false, $context);
```

Comment: There's no need to post this as an answer, you can just accept the suggested duplicate.