# file_get_contents() 'failed to open stream' error retrieving tweets

Tags: php, twitter, file-get-contents

I am trying to create a simple script that will retrieve the last 5 feeds for a twitter user (in this instance the BBC)

It runs okay locally on my development server but once I upload this to a live site I get the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=bbc&count=5): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in ....
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work on my live server (but fine on my dev server?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [file_get_contents throws 400 Bad Request error PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482782/file-get-contents-throws-400-bad-request-error-php), you may be better using curl instead of file_get_contents due to its improved error handling - this may provide you with another clue.

Comment: I've tried this but just get a returned value of NULL. Any ideas?

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uuw-b5c

Comment: First thing that stands out is that you're missing a _?_ between `user_timeline.json` and `include_entities=true`.

Comment: Done some additional research - as of Twitter API v1.1 they will no longer be accepting unauthorised requests so i'll need to use oAuth or something similar - this link seems the best method
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1

Comment: Cheers@celtis Got it working.. will post code here later for anyone else having a similar problem