# Unable to pass multiple arguments in php $_GET

Tags: c#, php, iis

I have the following php code which acts as proxy to my http server

slavePref.php

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://xyzdei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getServerUtil';

    $callback = $_GET["callback"];
    echo($callback . "(");
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo(file_get_contents($url . '/' . $_GET["poolingServer"], $_GET["serverPID"]));

    echo (")");
    ?>
```

The webservice hosted on IIS has the following contract

```
   [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionOnIPDWS))]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "getServerUtil/{poolingServer}&{serverPID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET")]
        //Status getServerUtil(string poolingServer,string serverPID, ref string oCreateResult); 
        string getServerUtil(string poolingServer, string serverPID);
```

From the browser I am trying to call the uri as

http://:1136/slavePerf.php?poolingServer=thunderw7dei&serverPID=23456

However the request is failing with the following message

>

```
 Notice: Undefined index: callback in C:\Users\xom\Documents\My Web
> Sites\EmptySite2\slavePerf.php on line 4  ( Warning:
> file_get_contents(http://xomw764dei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getServerUtil/thunderw7dei):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
> C:\Users\xom\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite2\slavePerf.php on line 8
> )
```

. I think I am not passing the arguments correctly

Comment: "However the request is failing" -> Errormessage?

Comment: @EdiG. I have updated the error message

Comment: Do you have parameter `callback` in your request part in URL?

Comment: @Mr.Smith I am calling it from a browser like http://localhost:1136/slavePerf.php?poolingServer=thunderw7dei&serverPID=23456

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar then there is the problem no callback parameter in URL and you are trying to get non-existing parameter's value

Comment: Test: url with echo $url . '/' . $_GET["poolingServer"] . '&' . $_GET["serverPID"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I modified my php file for file_get_contents

```
echo(file_get_contents($url . '/' . $_GET["poolingServer"]));
```

and my uriTemplate to

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getServerUtil/{poolingServer}/{serverPID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting a parameter called 'callback' and so it isn't set in the $_GET variables.

You could fix the error message by doing:

```
$callback = "";
if(array_key_exists('callback', $_GET) == TRUE){
    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
}
```

and add a '&' in the url:

```
echo(file_get_contents($url . '/' . $_GET["poolingServer"] . '&' . $_GET["serverPID"]))
```

Comment: Now its reporting 
Warning: file_get_contents(http://xomw764dei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getServerUtil/thunderw7dei&23456'): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\Users\xom\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite2\slavePerf.php on line 8

Comment: Is my uri template in the webservice correct 
 UriTemplate = "getServerUtil/{poolingServer}&{serverPID}"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482782/file-get-contents-throws-400-bad-request-error-php

Comment: The php response is  file_get_contents(http://xomw764dei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getServerUtil/thunderw7dei&amp;ABC): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  for the url 
http://localhost:1136/slavePerf.php?poolingServer=thunderw7dei&serverPID=ABC