# file_get_contents - HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents

Used to get content from a url through `file_get_contents`. Suddenly it stopped working, I get the "Warning: fopen(https://www.cba.am/am/SitePages/ExchangeArchive.aspx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/xocgzspq/public_html/rates/main/6zuohz.php on line xx" warning.

```
$url = "https://www.cba.am/am/SitePages/ExchangeArchive.aspx";
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
$html = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

BTW, getting the same issue with fopen instead of `file_get_contents`.
Haven't changed anything in the code recently, please, help to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce that but [HTTP 400](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) is **Bad Request** _The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications._ Maybe that server blocked you out?

Comment: Or try [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482782/file-get-contents-throws-400-bad-request-error-php?rq=1).

Comment: tried curl, got 302 error, added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, started to get 400 error. I guess the webpage is denying requests.

Comment: any workaround ? :(

Comment: If they blocked you out then no way to fix this. I don't know that do they have API for this, if there is then it is better to use their API.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue before I was facing this issue due to the proxy enabled in cloud flare after disabling it worked out.