# PHP: Http request fails from remote server

Tags: php, linux, macos, web-services, debian

I have some PHP code that calls a web service. It works perfectly when running on my local machine, but when I try to run it on the remote server (where it will ultimately reside), I get the following error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://XXXXXXXXX:8080/symws/rest/standard/searchCatalog?clientID=StorageClient&term1=ocm00576702): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 in /var/www/ShoppingCart/storage_request_button.php on line 42
```

My local machine is running OSX; the server is running debian linux.

Any idea what could be causing this different behavior? Is there another package I need to install on the server?

**UPDATE:**

While putting the URL in a browser works fine, when I try to wget the URL from the linux server, I get the 400 error. The server URL is accessing is also debian linux. There's no firewall on the server. I've never had to configure that server to allow access to it from anywhere else.

Comment: `file_get_content("http://XXXXXXXXX:8080/symws/rest/standard/searchCatalog?clientID=StorageClient&term1=ocm00576702")` what do you get ?

Comment: did you check if allow_url_fopen is set in your php.ini on the machine running the script?

Comment: file_get_content gives the same error.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is set to on.

Comment: Silly observation but you are connecting to port 8080 in your web thread. This is normally reserved for app servers (my tomcat serves from this port). Does this mean you are trying to load a page with an app on, not just a plain html page ? if so (and my knowledge is likely limited here) could this be your problem?

Comment: I am calling a web service that is running on a tomcat server, hence the 8080. Again, this url works in a browser and on my local machine, just not on the server.

Comment: This is not likely to be the problem but I HAVE seen it happen: are you sure you're looking at the right php.ini to make sure allow_url_fopen is on? Check php_info() to find out which php.ini file is actually being used.

Comment: is it possible to provide whole url for us to test? Your server side application might check request header and return 400 error if any required header info missed.

Comment: have u tried accessing the url http://xxxx:8080 from your server using a wget or curl request from shell. just to be sure your server's firewall are not blocking communication to this web service

Comment: Accessing the url using wget from the server gives the same error. So now we're on to something! I guess it's not a php thing. The server we're trying to access is also debian linux. So is this a firewall thing? I've never had to configure it to allow other systems to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think anyone was going to be able to help me with this one. Here's what it was: The server that was sending the request, storagews, was originally cloned from the server receiving the request, sws. Because of this, in storagews's etc/hosts file, the hostname "sws" was resolving to localhost. So it was trying to send the request to itself. It was raj_nt's comment that clued me in to this. If you want to make an answer, I'll give you the bounty.

Thanks for trying everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to supress errors as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710147/php-get-content-of-http-400-response) mentions to get rid of the status = 400. Perhaps with `simplexml_load_file('url', null, LIBXML_NOERROR);`

If it still doesnt work, there are a lot of things that can go wrong. `simplexml_load_file` doesnt have a lot of options to debug. You could try using `curl`.

```
<?php
// make request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://XXXXXXXXX:8080/symws/rest/standard/searchCatalog?clientID=StorageClient&term1=ocm00576702"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

// handle error; error output
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
  var_dump($output);
} else {

  //load xml
  $xml= simplexml_load_string($output);
}
curl_close($ch);

if (empty($xml)) {
  echo 'Something went wrong';
  exit;
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

Give this a try please and see if you get some info back:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://XXXXXXXXX:8080/symws/rest/standard/searchCatalog?clientID=StorageClient&term1=ocm00576702');
var_dump($http_response_header);
?>
```

Comment: the var_dump gives "bool(false)"

Comment: Scratch that...var_dump actually gives: string(0) ""

Comment: Added another test, perhaps that gives some more info. There is no obvious error in the url like some misplaced spaces or anything?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your URL is malformed.

Here's what the 400 code [means](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."

Comment: And why would the same URL work from my local machine? Is it automatically reforming it somehow?

Comment: Could it be that whatever XXXXXXXXX is is malformed, or that the server isn't correctly configured to respond to requests for XXXXXXXXX from the server?

Answer (score 0):

checkout the request being sent by simplexml_load_file.

you could also try accessing the 'url' directly in the browser (assuming you are performing a GET request)

you also need to consider the server side. Your server might be throwing a response with a 400 code even though everything is working normal. It might also not programmed to accept the request you are sending.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that file loads directly to Your browser. Check with CURL and spoof user-agent to one from Your browser. Try also to enable cookie feature.

here's some example: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-user-agent/

Comment: Have You tried passing user-agent in curl like I showed You in link?